# PHPUnit is printing (unwanted) JSON result

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, phpunit

After setting up `PHPUnit` with `Codeigniter` a couple months ago and running 2 or 3 simple tests everything seemed to be working fine.

When executing:
`php phpunit.phar --debug`

The result set was something like:

> Starting test 'Welcome_test::test_index'.. Starting test
>   'Welcome_test::test_method_404'.. Starting test
>   'Welcome_test::test_APPPATH'..
>
> Time: 1.23 seconds, Memory: 13.25 Mb
>
> OK (3 Tests, 3 Assertions)

After some time without using it, I went back and ran some simple tests again, but now the results include a `JSON` object:

```
{
    "event": "suiteStart",
    "suite": "Codeigniter Application Test Suite",
    "tests": 20
} {
    "event": "suiteStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "tests": 3
} {
    "event": "testStart",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "tests": "Welcome_test::test_index"
}
Starting test 'Welcome_test::test_index'.
{
    "event": "test",
    "suite": "Welcome_test",
    "tests": "Welcome_test::test_index",
    "status": "pass",
    "time": 0.00498656565,
    "trace": [],
    "message": "",
    "output": ""
} 
....

Time: 1.23 seconds, Memory: 13.25 Mb
OK (3 Tests, 3 Assertions)
```

That `JSON` output is making other stuff to break, but I don't remember doing anything to get that result.

Any ideas on what to do in order not to print that `JSON` result?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure nothing changed in the code between running the tests?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure nothing changed

Comment: @RobertDundon I went through recent changes. Nothing changed with the code but there were some changes with the configuration. .htaccess file was modified to remove index.php from the url when a request was made.